# MySQL yearweek() vs week() returning different result

Tags: mysql, sql, date

This simple query does not seem to be outputting the correct results. Given that the mode is the same (1) for all the functions shouldn't "week("2018-12-31", 1)" show a value of 1 rather than 53?

```
SELECT yearweek("2018-12-31", 1), yearweek("2019-01-02", 1),
week("2018-12-31", 1), week("2019-01-02", 1)
```

which outputs the following.

```
'201901','201901','53','1'
```

Is there a default dev more that I need to set somewhere?

Comment: 2018 doesn't have a week 53...

Comment: @jarlh That's the point of the question, why does MySql say it does, in one occasion?

Comment: @compufreak exactly

Comment: @jarlh 2018 has 53 weeks!
dec 30 and dec 31 of 2018 is week 53

Comment: @VishnuV, in 2018 week 52 is followed by week 1. (Some countries have their own rules.)

Comment: @VishnuV, all days in a week have the same week number, even for weeks that have some days in late December and some days in January the following year.

Comment: @jarlh please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54022121/9168603

Comment: @VishnuV: There's an international standard for defining weeks, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week, most countries adopted  ISO8601, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 (but some simply don't follow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this example from [`WEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function description:

> ```
> mysql> SELECT YEAR('2000-01-01'), WEEK('2000-01-01',0);
>         -> 2000, 0
> ```
>
> One might argue that `WEEK()` should return 52 because the given date
>   actually occurs in the 52nd week of 1999. `WEEK()` returns `0` instead so
>   that the return value is “the week number in the given year.”

The above seem to suggest that all modes having 0-53 range would return the week number relative to the year of input date (it'll return 0 if the date falls in the last week of the previous year).

So if first day of year = Monday and first week of year = having 4 or more days this year, then `2018-12-31` belongs to 53rd week of 2018 -and- 1st week of 2019, and the mode parameter determines the return value:

```
SELECT WEEK('2018-12-31', 1); -- 53
SELECT WEEK('2018-12-31', 3); -- 1
```

The [`YEARWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function is unambiguous (the result includes the year) so above does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

week() in mode 1: **First day of week is Monday and the first week of the year has more than 3 days.**

So 2018 started with week 1 and not from week 0 (because the week with 1st Jan 2018 had more than three days of 2018). Hence 31-12-2018 falls under week 53.

Similarly, 2019 starts with week 1 for 01-01-2019 until 06-01-2019 and week 2 from 07-01-2019 to 13-01-2019 (since Monday is first day of the week and the week containing Jan 1st has 6 days of 2019 )

Comment: So why does week("2019-01-02", 1) return 1? And how does this comply to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)?

Comment: @Compufreak all modes having 0-53 range would return the week number relative to the year of input date. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54021772/9168603 refer this answer for details

Comment: I am referring to the last part of your answer - you say 2019 starts with week 0, so why doesn't `week("2019-01-02", 1)` return 0? You also say `week("2019-01-07", 1)` is week 1, but it does return 2.

Comment: @Compufreak Oh I am so sorry, I might have mistyped. It is indeed week 1 because it contains 5 days of 2019. I will edit the answer

Comment: Btw, the week containing Jan 1st has *six* days in 2019